# Difference between Databinding methods

Tags: c#, data-binding, difference

Could anyone explain to me what is the difference between these two lines of code, and when I should use each?

```
.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Value", ds, "customers.CustToOrders.OrderDate"));

.DataBindings.Add("Value", ds, "customers.CustToOrders.OrderDate");
```

Comment: It doesn't look to me as though there is any difference at all.  The first `Add` overload could be useful if it were used with a pre-constructed object (rather than a throw-away temporary) that might be re-used or shared.

Comment: You're adding a new Binding in both cases. The first method can be used when you have a Binding declared as `var myBinding = new Binding("Value", ds, "customers.CustToOrders.OrderDate");`, then you can add a handler to, for example, the `Parse` event as `myBinding.Parse += (obj, evt) => { // Do something }`  then add the Binding: `.DataBindings.Add(myBinding);`. Btw, that's C# code, but you tagged the question as VB.Net (not that there's any difference, but tag as you code).

Comment: It's not super-important but your code is c# so why tag as vb.net? You will get much more attention with a c# tag...